# how to create server on port 80 using node.js under Apache and Win7?

Tags: windows, apache, node.js

When I try to open port 80 in node.js using this code (helloWorld)

```
          var http = require('http');
          var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
          response.writeHead(200);
          response.end("Hello World\n");
          });

          server.listen(80);
```

but it doesn't work, only if i give it port `8000` or something else.
since i work under win7 i open the cmd with right click and then run as administrator but it seems it doesn't run like a root under linux.

[image]

Comment: Does Apache already have port 80 open?

Comment: You have already implemented a webserver so you don't need apache.

Comment: that's what weird the apache is closed and i run the cmd as admin.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Nodejs has a stable release for Windows

This will allow you to run Node.js on Windows without the need to integrate with Apache which is sweet.

Download and Release Details - http://blog.nodejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

do you have any MSSQL instance running on your machine?

Try: netstat -n -n -o