# Trigger.io forge run web

Tags: trigger.io

I'm getting some random errors when running:

```
forge run web
```

in my app.

```
$ forge run web
[   INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.11
[   INFO] Checking JavaScript files...
[   INFO] JavaScript check complete
[   INFO] Verifying your configuration settings...
[   INFO] Configuration settings check complete
[   INFO] { [Error: listen EADDRINUSE] code: 'EADDRINUSE', errno: 'EADDRINUSE', syscall: 'listen' }
```

Any idea what might cause this error?

Comment: It sounds like some stray node processes are remaining, have you tried the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is cause by an application already listening on the port you're trying to listen on.

You can use `ps aux | grep node` to see if there are any node processes running.
Then kill them using `kill pid` where pid is the process id

example:

```
ps aux | grep node
37211   0.0  0.2  3029484  17852 s018  S+    5:35PM   0:00.28 node ./web.js
kill 37211
```