# EADDRINUSE - still can't kill the Node Process

Tags: node.js

I'm running terminal in webstorm.  I try running node --harmony app.js and says my koa app.listen() is already running.

So I try to hunt and see what node processes are running via the command ps aux | grep node

I see a couple results:

```
myUserName         897   0.0  0.0  3083844    160 s000  T    11:15AM   0:00.32 node --harmony app.js
myUserName        1935   0.0  0.0  2441988    676 s000  S+    1:33PM   0:00.00 grep node
```

I try to kill 897 by doing a kill 897 or pkill 897 but it is still running.  How do I get that to kill!!!??

Comment: Have you tried kill -9 897?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4075287/783510

Comment: Perhaps not the right site for this either. Doesn't have to do with node, has to do with operating system and killing processes.

Comment: Worth noting that something else entirely could be listening on your desired port (for instance Skype claims 443, at least on windows)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`kill -9 897`

[kill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command sends a signal to the given process, but unless you use -9 which sends the `SIGKILL` signal, the process is allowed to attempt to kill itself.

Answer (score 4):

> fuser -k 4060/tcp

where 4060 is the port on which your node server is running.

Comment: What makes this different from kill? Because this worked, and kill didn't?