# Strange node.js error trying to start express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I can start my app using nodemon, just by typing `nodemon`

but got below error when I do `node app.js`

[image]

My package.json is configured properly. It has

`"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }`

Comment: There is a process, maybe a previous execution, that have lock the port number you try to bind. Try to change the port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is already in use, there might be another instance of your application already running. To see what processes are running background use `netstat -tlpn` and to filter node only processes `netstat -tlpn | grep node`.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22917/node          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8666          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      358/node            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8667          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4416/node
```

As you see the port 8081 is already taken, try to kill it and start you server again `kill 22917`.

Comment: any idea why I tried to run pm2 start app.js in my express app and it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you get any error messages, if yes please post here.

Comment: I made it. I do `pm2 start www/bin` it worked! that's so strange, any idea why? I'm on express 4

Comment: If you do use the generator example, the app.js is just another module which does not start the server itself http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html. The http server listen has been moved to `www/bin` in your case https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/templates/js/www.

Comment: so express generator and express from scratch is designed differently?!

Comment: There is no fixed project layout, as it's in express generator the express application has separated into module. This enables the testing easier with `supertest` and `superagent` modules etc.

Answer (score 1):

`EADDRINUSE` means that a port your node application attempted to bind to, has already been bound to by another process. Typically this suggests you haven't killed your last node process before starting the current one, or you haven't configured your application to use the correct port (e.g., a system port that can't be bound to, or a port below 1024 which requires administrative access to bind to).

Answer (score 0):

there is something in use, try to restart your machine and try again.
=D

Comment: my machine means what? I'm having that error on a cloud server

Comment: well, try to restart that server, looks like already have a proccess running and its locking a creation of a new instance.

Comment: you could try this solution too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server