# eaddrinuse error i don't know what to do

Tags: javascript

```
[2018-02-11T14:41:44.981] [DEBUG] default - { Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/home/bot/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:237:9)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/bot/site.js:770:29)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8000 }
```

So i readed about this error and i understood that i need to make config file somewhere with some script in it but that's the problem i don't know where do i make it in this situation

Comment: Windows task manager stop node process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Answer (score 0):

This error means you already have something running on port 8000 (probably another instance of your app). Close or kill that process and restart.

P.S. If you are on a UNIX-based system you can run `lsof -i 9000` and then `kill` process by name.

Comment: Yes i have tried it and when i run  lsof -i 9000 i get this lsof: unknown protocol name (9000) in: -i 9000

Comment: Now i figured it out i wrote command lsof -i:8000 and i got nothing so that means there is nothing running on the port 8000 but if its still giving eaddrinuse what should i do?!?!?