# Nodemon and Redwood-Broker

Tags: javascript, macos, express, nodemon

I am running Nodemon in an express app, and I've done no special configuration; in my package.json I have this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "nodemon app/app.js"
}
...
```

Everything goes fine until I make changes, and Nodemon goes to restart. I get an `EADDRINUSE` error, so I'll try and restart completely and I get the same error.

After this, I started checking for anything running on port 3001 (which is what Nodemon is supposed to run on), and get something like the following output:

```
$ lsof -i :3001
COMMAND   PID    USER         FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    54343    myUserName   11u  IPv6 0x1bdae98886f3261d      0t0  TCP *:redwood-broker (LISTEN)
```

If I kill that process, I can finally restart Nodemon, but the same thing will happen the next time I make changes to the files being watched by Nodemon.

After scouring the Internet, I've seen some mentions of `redwood-broker`, but nothing helpful so far. Has anyone seen this behavior with Nodemon?

I'm using the following:

Express 4.16.2

Nodemon version 1.15.1

2016 MacBook Pro with Sierra 10.12.6

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try to close your process with `control+c`

Comment: your problem is already discussed here > [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Comment: I can stop the process with `control+c`, but that's not the issue. Also, the link you attached is referring to when the process crashes; whether Nodemon restarts itself, crashes, or is 'gracefully' shut down, it always leaves the child processes running. It may not be Nodemon, either; I'm not sure what the redwood-broker process is, because other machines don't necessarily have that process even when they are using Nodemon.

Comment: hmm i dont know more. may be give a try to kill node and change its port

Comment: This particular issue in nodemon is being tracked on github here https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1247 - it's not solved yet because it can't be replicated by me (nodemon's author) and no one has been able to send a PR for it yet. But any additional info is welcomed.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I will follow that issue. Reading through it, I don't see anything that is different in my case, besides the fact that there is always that `redwood-broker` process running... Is that related to nodemon? Also, is it pronounced 'No demon' or 'Node mon'?

Comment: Curious if anyone ever determined what `redwood-broker` is.

Answer (score 4):

This issue happens to a few people. You could do below to try:

**Option 1:**

sudo pkill node

**Option 2:**

1. sudo lsof -i :5955

Then kill the process which is currently running on the port using its PID

2. sudo kill -9 PID

Hope it helps