# I can't run the node.js server in localhost

Tags: node.js, localhost

I am  beginner in node.js programming. I did the simple program. I am running this program in localhost 8086.I am using Webstorm to execute this.This program works perfectly last two weeks. Suddenly it shows the error. I cannot able to run this program in localhost. It shows the error event in (port listen 8086). Can anyone solve this issue? Thanks in advance..

[image: Error]

```html
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
app.get("/abc",function(request,response)
{
    response.send("I got a request");
    console.log("I got a request");
});
app.listen(8086,function()
{
    console.log("server running at port 8086");
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Comment: Did you try rebooting first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another application is already using that port. Check if you installed / started another software that might use the port 8086.

Comment: Thankyou for all of your concern.I closed the application completely and I executed again.It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`EARDRINUSE` means that the port is already in use.

You had run another server use the same port like 8086 (in your case).

Maye you had run `node app` in other terminal in WebStorm. Please close it and run it again.

You can check PORT no. is available or not using by
`netstat -tulnp | grep <port no>`

Comment: Thank you for all of your concern.I closed the application completely and I executed again.It works perfectly