# webpack-dev-server keep port alive after closing

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server

I have a vue app created with the webpack-simple template.

I want to use an static port, so I hard code the port in the devServer property in the file webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true,
        overlay: true,
        port: 1123
    },
```

The first time that I run npm run dev everything works fine. After I close the process with `ctrl+c` (using git bash in windows) and retry running npm run dev an error occurs telling me that the port is currently in use. If I change the port the first time it works then it repeats the same error (again and again).

I check the processs that is using the ports and it's node. I don't understand why node keep listening to those ports after I hit `ctrl+c`.

My dev script:

```
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot"
```

**Info**

```
OS: Windows
Terminal: Git Bash
Node: v9.5.0
NPM: v5.6.0
Webpack: 3.6.0
Webpack-Dev-Server: 2.9.1
```

Comment: FWIW, https://github.com/Microsoft/node-pty/issues/7 may be the issue. I was seeing the same thing and upgrading Git (with bash) to 2.18.0 seems to have resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the process exits abruptly, it doesn't close cleanly the listening server. The node process is terminated but the operating systems keeps the port open (in `TIME_WAIT` state) for a given amount of time to allow for the queues of packets to empty (see the [socket FAQ](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-4.html) and section ["2.7 Please explain the TIME_WAIT state."](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq-2.html#time_wait).
In node, you can mitigate this problem by trying to close the server on `exit` and `uncaughtException` events. See this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server) to a related question.

Comment: I have the same issue and the node process is not terminated (it can be seen via the windows task manager) but not via `ps` in the shell, and the socket is not in a `TIME_WAIT` status, it is still `LISTENING` as seen via `netstat -ao`. It is almost as if the node process has been dissociated from the bash shell.