# Kill node process in linux

Tags: node.js, linux

While trying to run node server using node server.js, I get the error to listen EADDRINUSE :::4002. I get the process listening on port 4002 by the command: sudo lsof -i :4002. After that I try to kill the process using kill -9 . The problem is when I run sudo lsof -i :4002 command again after killing the process, I see the node process running again with a different proces id.

The node server was started by a different user and I am trying to kill it with another user.

Comment: check if it's controlled by something like supervisor or pm2

Comment: @bambam Yes, indeed it is controlled by pm2. Can I kill it?

Comment: pm2 list -> pm2 stop <processId showed by pm2>

Comment: @bambam pm2 list does not show anything probably because pm2 is run by another user.

Comment: Do you have root privileges? If so, run `sudo pm2 list`

Comment: @bambam I do have root privileges. Running sudo pm2 list did not give me anything either.

Comment: Hm. That makes it harder... You can try to run `sudo -u <user who is running the process> pm2 list`. Does this return something?

Comment: @bambam yes it does. 2 running servers.

Comment: Cool. Then you can also delete the process like that

Comment: @bambam Yes I was able to using:   sudo -u <user who is running the process> pm2 stop all. Thanks!! Not sure if I can mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075287/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've discussed that the process is managed and automatically restarted by pm2, you'll have to stop the pm2 process instead of just killing the node process. To do that, run the following commands

```
sudo -u <user who is running the process> pm2 list
```

You'll now find all processes the given user has started. From here, take the id(s) of the process you want to stop, then run (to stop a single process)

```
sudo -u <user who is running the process> pm2 stop <id>
```

or to simply stop them all

```
sudo -u <user who is running the process> pm2 stop all
```

> Note that `sudo -u` is only needed because the processes are run by
>   another user. If you want to stop a process your current user has
>   created, omit the `sudo -u <user>` part

Answer (score 1):

Try this cmd in the terminal to kill all node process :

```
killall node
```

Comment: The process seems to be automatically restarted. How does this answer solve the problem at hand?

Comment: this answer just helps you kill all node process you have to diagnostics your system to see if you have any backgrounds worker that's start this process :/

Answer (score 1):

1. 'netstat -nptl' to see all the processes
2. kill -9 3887 (E.g Node is running over 3887/node)

Comment: The process seems to be automatically restarted. How does this answer solve the problem at hand? –

Comment: As I can see your above comments and understand your problem, you want to remove pm2 scripts on start. To automatically start all nodejs processes on startup, command is `pm2 startup` and exactly opposite command is `pm2 unstartup`, to remove all nodejs startup processes, which is what i think you are asking for.