# I have a bug when running my jhipster app with npm start

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, webpack-dev-server, jhipster-registry

I'm beginner on jhipster and i have some bug. i don't know why... I have a bug when running my jhipster app with npm start.

```
$ npm start

    > agrosfer@0.0.0 start C:\Users\pc\Desktop\acumen_network\DEV0408181449
    > yarn run webpack:dev

    yarn run v1.7.0
    $ yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base
    warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the
    scripts.
    $ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base
     10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active[HPM] Proxy created: [ '/api',
      '/management',
      '/swagger-resources',
      '/v2/api-docs',
      '/h2-console',
      '/auth' ]  ->  http://127.0.0.1:8080
    events.js:183
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

    Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:9060
        at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
        at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
        at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1505:7)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Looks like you've already got something running on that port (9060)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because of breakable end the process, like stop your jhipster server. when you close the server using Ctrl+C, sometimes what happens your server closed not successfully, for that you have to completely stop that process and run again.

Run below command in cmd:

1. netstat -ano | findstr 9000
2. taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F

Answer (score 0):

Your port `9060` is in use as the error message `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:9060` suggest.

You can either change port or [find](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/) and deal with the other application who is using that port.