# Nodejs express error shows events.js:167 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^

Tags: node.js, express

> bash: /Users/abdurahman/.bash_profile: line 9: syntax error:
>   unexpected end of file Abdus-Air-5:FcExam abdurahman$ nodemon run
>   server [nodemon] 1.18.10 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
>   [nodemon] watching: *.* [nodemon] starting node run server server.js
>   events.js:167
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000enter code
>   here

Comment: You can follow this post to solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4075287/5589964

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of some other process running on port 5000.
If you are using linux:

```
lsof -i:5000 | grep 5000
```

This command will give you the pid of the process running on port 5000 and then you can kill the process by

```
kill -9 <pid>
```