# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080 while clicking on run script

Tags: node.js, express

Firstly I run this command (`npm ndb server.js`) then a debugging chrome window appear and after this
Actually, I got these error when I am trying to debug in my code and I clicked on run script after that a debugging chrome window appear then it give these wired error.

```
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1279:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1327:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1414:7)
at Function.listen (C:\Users\Abhishek kumar\natours\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abhishek kumar\natours\server.js:24:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at emitErrorNT (net.js:1306:8)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Comment: can you specify the OS?

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar you might have tried to rerun your server or some other process might be using that port

Comment: There is one server instance is already running which is using port 8080.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty windows 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/1203844 follow this. end the process where you see port is 8080.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server Please check

Comment: npx kill-port 8080

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite explicit :

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8080

means that some program is already listening on port `8080` (and you have an extra hint : the `:::` says that it's listening on broadcast host using IPv6).

If you're curious what program is listening on that port, you could try to navigate to `http://localhost:8080` and see what's displayed. If nothing is displayed then it's not one of your web apps. Maybe you have an HTTP proxy running  on your machine (I have recently come across a malware that ran `mitmproxy` on target machines on port `8080` to intercept all traffic).

On Mac or Linux you can use `lsof` to get more information on the program listening on that port.

The command you want is :

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8080
```

Comment: This is a nice way to see what is running on that port. To kill the process type either, kill [PID] or killall node (node is the process command name)

Answer (score -1):

Run this command.

```
killall node
```

Comment: What operating system are you answering for?

Comment: The comments below the question reveal that OP is using Windows 10.

Comment: Try this for window- taskkill /im node.exe