# Node Server Ports keep getting 'Plugged Up' during development

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I'm over a month into development of a MEVN app with MySQL. I'm using a framework called MEVN-CLI but that shouldn't really matter.

I keep having to change my server port ever few days whenever I get this error:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,html,css,json,md
[nodemon] starting `node run server.js --port 9000/api --open`
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1309:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1445:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Dev\Projects\node-mysql\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\Projects\node-mysql\server\server.js:258:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1336:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
```

I change between 9000, 3000, 3002, 8000, etc. I want to keep it on a single port but this keeps happening and I can't find what's causing it.

I have a client and a server, they communicate with Axios, my Server communicates with a MySQL server I host elsewhere but I also think this is irrelevant but I figure it can't hurt to share that.

Here is my server:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const env = require("./env.json");
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const favicon = require("serve-favicon");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const {
  testColumns,
  showUsers,
  searchResultColumns,
  showAccountColumns
} = require("./mysql/columns");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico")));
app.use(cors());

//* Build MySQL Connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: env.server,
  user: env.user,
  password: env.pass,
  database: env.schema
});

//* Connect to Database
db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error Connecting:", err);
  }
  console.log("MySQL Connected...");
});

app.get(`/api/v1/:query/:x`, (req, res) => {
[Business Logic - Works fine]
    if (err) {
      // If error
      console.log(err);
    }
    // If no results
    else if (results == 0) {
      res.send(`No Results\n ${results} \n - ${err}`);
      return;
    }
    // If successful
    res.send(results);
  });
});

app.get(`/api/v1/:query/`, (req, res) => {
[Business Logic - Works fine]
    if (err) {
      // If error
      console.log(err);
    }
    // If no results
    else if (results == 0) {
      res.send(`No Results\n ${results} \n - ${err}`);
      return;
    }
    // If successful
    res.send(results);
  });
});

//* Root Handler
app.get("/", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"))
);

//? Error Handler
app.get("/404", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/404.html"))
);

//! Error Handler
app.get("/sample", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/sample.html"))
);

//? Listen for server port
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Sample Dev Server at:${port}`);
});
```

I deleted some stuff that's not really relevant because it was hundreds of similar lines, I haven't abstracted my routing away yet.

This is my router:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import NotFound from "./views/NotFound.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/NotFound",
      name: NotFound,
      component: () => import("./views/NotFound.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/search",
      component: searchPage,
      children: [
        { path: "/search/byName", component: searchByName },
        { path: "/search/china", component: searchByNumber }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

And if it's relevant, this is my packages.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vmax",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

I changed just now to port 4000 and it's working just find but something is wrong that's causing me to have to change server ports every few days.

Comment: Dupe of [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server), this issue is more apparent on windows

Answer (score 1):

Probably the PORT is in use.
To terminate program PORT,

```
$ killall -9 node
```

Answer (score 0):

**Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use** happens when closing VS Code, particularly on Windows when a server is running with WSL.

I'm currently using [something called CurrPorts](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) which is free to view which ports are in use, and force close them.

To be clear, it's not specific to Windows or WSL, but that is where it seems most prevalent. If you're in the habit of using port 3000, 5500, or 8080 for example - it's likely in use by Node.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your "package.json" file

```
"stop-win": "Taskkill /IM node.exe /F",
"stop-linux": "killall node"
```