# npm "concurrently" mode EADDRINUSE

Tags: npm, concurrently

The idea is to run 3 create-react-app instances at once:

alias runMicro='cd /Users/USERNAME/Documents/microfrontend/app-container; concurrently "yarn start --prefix /Users/USERNAME/Documents/microfrontend/micro-frontend" "yarn start --prefix /Users/USERNAME/Documents/microfrontend/micro-frontend2" "yarn start --prefix /Users/USERNAME/Documents/microfrontend/micro-frontend3" "npm start"'

If you try to run that alias command I run into this problem:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000
```

Basically it throws the message **3 times**. The other apps are set to run at POPRT 4002, 4003, 4004 respectively. If I remove 2 of them it only throws the error message EADDRINUSE once.

Also, tried

"start": "concurrently "yarn start" "cd ../micro-frontend && yarn start" "cd ../micro-frontend2 && yarn start" "cd ../micro-frontend3 && yarn start"" but it as well results in infinte loo[image]p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri not really, nothing is currently running on port 3000. What I think happens is that it simply tries to run app-container 3 times