# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000

Tags: node.js, graphql, nodemon

I've been on this post for the answer: [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Although I don't think that it answers my question, as I wouldn't like to kill the running process but to restart the service.

```
$ npm run start

> graphql-basics@1.0.0 start /home/phill/Documents/graphql-course/graphql-basics
> nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node

[nodemon] 1.17.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
The server is up!


[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000
```

Basically it restarts the server without killing the previous process?

> Manually killing the process won't fix this issue

this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "graphql-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon src/index.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

```js
const server = new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
})

server.start(() => {
    console.log('The server is up!')
})

//should i use process.on('SIGTERM',...) and kill it somehow?
```

Comment: try removing `  --exec babel-node ` from the start script then kill the process manually, then `npm start` again

Comment: did you try it? I can't run `graphql` without it

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 option to resolve this issue.

1. Execute `killall node` command using root user
2. Set the available port. `var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;`

Answer (score 2):

Nodemon offers a delay option. I solved it by inserting that option in the same situation as you. Please refer to the link below. [github.com/nodemon/delaying-restarting](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#delaying-restarting)

`"start": "nodemon --delay 300ms src/index.js --exec babel-node"`

```yaml
{
  "name": "graphql-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --delay 300ms src/index.js --exec babel-node",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.14.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: uhm for some reason the delay didn't change much

Comment: Is it even if I increase the delay?

Comment: Looks like a different problem in you case`:(`
It's hard to test because the situation doesn't reproduce error. Does it work normally when I delete --exec babel-node? I am curious if there is any dependency on `babel-node`

Comment: I found a similar issue below, please refer to it. It is unfortunate that it cannot help. https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1477

Comment: yes indeed it's weird I'll take a look at it. Probably a version issue

Comment: @myeongkilkim, you are efficient . Works fine for me,but I had to push at 1000ms.