# Nodejs Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

My app was not running but when I try `"npm start"` command it throws error

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :8080`

I restart my EC2 instance and try this command again, but I face same error.  How do I start my Node server?

Comment: Do you have another process/server running at the same time? Also please provide a minimal reproducible sample or at least more context

Comment: @MrCodingB No I didn't running any other process, for confusion I restart my ec2 instance but still I am facing this error.

Comment: run `netstat -p -l | grep 8080` to see which process holds port 8080

Comment: @obe this command shows nothing......

Comment: @AmitShakya Do you see anything with ```ps -eaf|grep 8080``` or ```lsof -i tcp:8080```

Comment: Have you checked you're not having your node app call `app.listen(8080)` twice by accident?

Comment: @IAmDranged yes I have checked that, even I have restart my server instance as well to remove all confusion. but still facing this issue

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan I got this output lsof -i tcp:8080 -> node    3255 root   20u  IPv6  20660      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)  ||
 ps -eaf|grep 8080 -> root      5251  4938  0 19:22 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 8080
What does it mean??? I  am new for Node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by your comments, it looks like you have a node process already running your EC2 instance and it's listening on port 8080.
As you have stated `lsof -i tcp:8080` gives you,

```
node 3255 root 20u IPv6 20660 0t0 TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
```

The PID of this process is shown in the 2nd column: 3255.
Kill it,

```
kill -9 3255
```

After this try running your `npm start` and it should work