# nodemon package Throws Error Everytime I update js files behaviour: "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern, nodemon

I'm trying to build a nodeapi for which I am using bunch of libs like express, morgan, nodemon.
Everything was correctly installed with no error in installation
and when I try to use nodemon by updating in package.json file it work for one time then it shooting [is showing? reporting? an] unexpected error

here the error on terminal

```
> node@1.0.0 start /root/Downloads/node
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server Has Been Started
localhost:3000
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Downloads/node/server.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here's My app.js looks like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan =require('morgan')

const employeeRoutes =require('./api/routes/employee');
const departmentRoutes =require('./api/routes/department');

app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Routes for api 
app.use('/employee',employeeRoutes);
app.use('/department',departmentRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

And here is my server.js

```
const http=require('http');
const app =require('./app');

const port =process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);

console.log('Server Has Been Started');
console.log('localhost:'+port);
```

I am using postman to access all request and response.

I did try using `npm cache clean --force`
but it's not working anymore.

Comment: See below thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server

Comment: @kraa How Many Times I Have to go and manually kill the thread pls provided appropritate solution

Answer (score 0):

Experienced something like this before, just try rebooting your system that should fix the issue

Comment: If i reboot my system all the dependencies and libraries will be flashed out i.e. pls providing some meaningful and logical explanation of this problem