# Axios + React "uncaught (in promise) error / internal 500 server error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am using react, node and mongoDB to upload videos into a media bucket, then upload and be able to stream the video. everything works until I click upload and I get the following error. [uncaught(in promise error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbW0o.png)

Here is my following code for app.js please let me know if you need to see more of the code [Here is the line of code where I am getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHk4r.png)

Comment: Please replace the images with a text-based [mcve]. We cannot debug images

Comment: A 500 http error says that there is an error with the server itself, not the react code calling it

Comment: okay I am new to react and my react is working so assumed my server was working. I ran my server alone and got a error  "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000"

Comment: Using node? Have a read of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server