# How to run nodejs application in bluehost server without port number. eg: www.mydomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com:8080. Thanks for advance

Tags: node.js, bluehost

How to run nodejs application in bluehost server without port number. eg: **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)** instead of **[www.mydomain.com:8080](http://www.mydomain.com:8080)**

Comment: Server runs with port number. Servers ran with DNS has also port numbers(for http server  80, for https 443 normaly). As I haven't used bluehost I couldn't give you an exact answer but if you run nodejs server based on http you should use port 80.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jacobkim but in bluehost server port 80 is default port. so it will thrw err code: 'EADDRINUSE',

Comment: The port 80 is for http server. Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)?