# How do I kill a hanging TestCafe process using :::57664

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using TestCafe to test an app I'm working on. Today, when I went to run a TC test, I got the following message:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::57664`

I can usually handle these pretty easily: I issue the command:

`lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"`
or
`lsof -i tcp:57664`

and then kill the offending task that is identified.
However, in this case, that port number isn't listed so I don't know which task to kill. also,

`ps aux | grep -i "TestCafe"`

doesn't show anything helpful.

Any suggestions on how to identify the hung task and kill it?

Comment: I've been running into this issue lately a lot as well and I haven't found a solution either. So I'm curious regarding the suggestions for this issue. In order to kill hanging node processes, `killall -9 node` was [suggested as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server). Though, this did not solve the problem in my case either.

Comment: @MartinH.  Killing all node tasks is definitely not an option here (throwing the baby out with the bathwater, IMO). I'm running 20+ node tasks (Obsidian, neovim, Azure data studio & helper, copilot, ...). I sure don't want to restart half my work just to kill TestCafe!

Comment: yup, I definitely agree with you on that. That would only be an option if TestCafè is the only (relevant) node process running.

Comment: interestingly, I completely stopped experiencing this issue after upgrading my macOS from Big Sur to Monterey.