# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...........mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I have this problem
after I connect my file `app.js` with mongo database.
when I use the command `npm run watch` or `nodemon app`
it works for a second then that happens:
[image: a]

and this happened after I wrote this lines of code:
[image: b]
I tried to connect with new mongoDB account ..and it's the same

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying ot listen for connections on a port that is already in use. `EADDRINUSE`.

Before `mongoose.connect()` line, you are listening for connections on port `300` with `app.listen(port)`.

Then after handling the promise success `.then()`, you are doing the same, also listening for connections on the same port `300` with `app.listen(port)`.

### Solution:

Remove `app.listen(port)` line before `// for DB` comment.

Comment: thankyou i got you ... and you solved my problem <3