# Facing an issue in nodejs pm2

Tags: node.js

Facing an issue in nodejs app

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1463:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1511:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1599:7)
at Object. (/root/wa_server/app.js:209:11)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1490:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -98,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 8000
}

sudo killall -9 node

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - Kill server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server)

Answer (score 0):

A program in your system is already running and using your 8000 port. You have to stop or kill it first. As it appears it is most likely a NodeJS process in your case which is running somewhere (in background if not foreground). You can kill the nodejs process to release the occupied port.

Comment: I tried many things to find and kill this process but only 1 process is running when i kill this my current is kill and on next start same message coming Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000 
i tried to change port but not success on every port same message.

Comment: Then more context will be needed on how the code is listening to port, or how the program is being executed, or you can try `netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8000'` or similar commands (if linux) to check for associated process.