# How to fix "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000" Unhandled 'error' event?

Tags: node.js, express

I tried the method delete node_modules and reinstall it, but it didnt work

here's my server index.js

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1872:16)     
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1920:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:2008:7)
    at Function.listen (D:\TMDT\e-commerce-furniture\server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at file:///D:/TMDT/e-commerce-furniture/server/server.js:23:5    
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:25)   
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1899:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You have something running on that port. What operating system are you on? Deleting node modules would do nothing here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please research your question before posting in accordance with [ask]. Duplicate of [Node / Express: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use - how can I stop the process using the port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-how-can-i-stop-the-process)

Answer (score -1):

This error basically means the port 5000 is already being used by some other service.You can either change the port number to something else or you need to kill that process running on that port.In terminal You can do
`sudo lsof -ti:5000`
It will list all the processes running on port 5000 . Then
`kill <PID>`  and the error will go.
This pid you can find from the list you got using above command